# How to use reverseclip with a rectangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I want to use `reverseclip` with this picture. 
First way.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current bounding box.south west)rectangle 
            (current bounding box.north east)} }} 
\begin{document} 
    %polar coordinates of visibility 
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{330} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.5,line join = round, line cap = round] 
    \coordinate (B) at (0, 0, 0); 
    \coordinate (Q) at ({-3*sqrt(15)/4}, -3/4, 0); 
    \coordinate (A) at ($ 2*(Q) - (B) $); 
    \coordinate (C) at (0, 4, 3); 
    \coordinate (D) at (0, 0, 3); 
    \coordinate (P) at (0, 2, 3); 

    \coordinate (R) at (0, 2, 0); 
    \coordinate (M) at ($ 3.5*(R) - (B) $); 
    \coordinate (X) at (-7,-3,0);
    \coordinate (Y) at (-7,3,0);
    \coordinate (Z) at (2,3,0);
    \coordinate (T) at (2,-3,0);

    \foreach \v/\position in {A/below,B/below, D/above,P/above,C/above,R/below,Q/below} {\draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$}; 
    } 

    \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) --cycle 
    (A) -- (D) (Y) -- (X) -- (T) -- (Z) ;
    ; 
    \draw [dashed] (P) -- (Q) --(R) --cycle 
    (B) -- (C) 
    ; 

\begin{scope} 
\draw [dashed](Y)--  (Z); 
\clip (C) --  (A) -- (B) --  (D) -- cycle [reverseclip]; 
\draw [ thick](Y)--  (Z); 
\end{scope} 

    \tkzMarkRightAngle(D,B,A); 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,D,C); 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,R,Q); 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

I got the correct result
[image]

**Second way** (I got incorrect result)

```
     \documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone} 
    \usepackage{fouriernc} 
    \usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds} 
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
    \usetkzobj{all} 
    \usepackage{pgfplots} 
    \tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current bounding box.south west)rectangle 
                (current bounding box.north east)} }} 
    \begin{document} 
        %polar coordinates of visibility 
        \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{330} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.5,line join = round, line cap = round] 
        \coordinate (B) at (0, 0, 0); 
        \coordinate (Q) at ({-3*sqrt(15)/4}, -3/4, 0); 
        \coordinate (A) at ($ 2*(Q) - (B) $); 
        \coordinate (C) at (0, 4, 3); 
        \coordinate (D) at (0, 0, 3); 
        \coordinate (P) at (0, 2, 3); 

        \coordinate (R) at (0, 2, 0); 
        \coordinate (M) at ($ 3.5*(R) - (B) $); 

        \foreach \v/\position in {A/below,B/below, D/above,P/above,C/above,R/below,Q/below} {\draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$}; 
        } 

        \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) --cycle 
        (A) -- (D) 
        ; 
        \draw [dashed] (P) -- (Q) --(R) --cycle 
        (B) -- (C) 
        ; 

    \begin{scope} [canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape] 
\draw [dashed] 
(-7,-3) rectangle (2,3); 
\clip (C)-- (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- cycle [reverseclip]; 
\draw[thick] (-7,-3) rectangle (2,3); 
\end{scope}

        \tkzMarkRightAngle(D,B,A); 
        \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,D,C); 
        \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,R,Q); 
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{document}
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

How can I use `reverseclip` with a rectangle like second way?

Comment: where do you use `reverseclip` in second example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you use `reverseclip` in a scope that transforms you in a plane. So if you replace

```
\clip (C)-- (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- cycle [reverseclip];
```

by

```
\clip[draw] (C)-- (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- cycle [reverseclip];
```

you get

[image]

which explains the result: Ti*k*Z didn't draw the bounding box rectangle but a projected rectangle with the same south west and north east corners as the bounding box. One way to solve this is to use

```
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={
(current bounding box.south west) --(current bounding box.north west)
 --(current bounding box.north east) --  (current bounding box.south east)
 -- cycle} }}
```

instead.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={
(current bounding box.south west) --(current bounding box.north west)
 --(current bounding box.north east) --  (current bounding box.south east)
 -- cycle} }} 
\begin{document} 
    %polar coordinates of visibility 
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{330} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1.5,line join = round, line cap = round] 
    \coordinate (B) at (0, 0, 0); 
    \coordinate (Q) at ({-3*sqrt(15)/4}, -3/4, 0); 
    \coordinate (A) at ($ 2*(Q) - (B) $); 
    \coordinate (C) at (0, 4, 3); 
    \coordinate (D) at (0, 0, 3); 
    \coordinate (P) at (0, 2, 3); 

    \coordinate (R) at (0, 2, 0); 
    \coordinate (M) at ($ 3.5*(R) - (B) $); 

    \foreach \v/\position in {A/below,B/below, D/above,P/above,C/above,R/below,Q/below} {\draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$}; 
    } 

    \draw[thick] (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- (C) --cycle 
    (A) -- (D) 
    ; 
    \draw [dashed] (P) -- (Q) --(R) --cycle 
    (B) -- (C) 
    ; 

    \begin{scope} [canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape] 
    \draw [dashed] 
    (-7,-3) rectangle (2,3); 
    \clip (C)-- (A) -- (B) -- (D) -- cycle [reverseclip]; 
    \draw[thick] (-7,-3) rectangle (2,3); 
    \end{scope}

    \tkzMarkRightAngle(D,B,A); 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(B,D,C); 
    \tkzMarkRightAngle(P,R,Q); 
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]